# Encoding the data for use in WebView Android

Tags: android, wordpress

Good day,
I have an app to display the posts of a web (wordpress). I'm using the wordpress rest api and I show the content of the posts in a WebView, but when I run the app and select a post, strange characters are seen in the content eg A3n instead of the accented / or).
I have the following line of code where I define the encoding:

Content.loadData (listAdapter.get (id) .getContent (). GetRendered (), "text / html", "UTF-8");

Because I think I understand that the rest-api of wordpress return the json encoded in UTF-8

Any solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Content.loadData (listAdapter.get (id) .getContent (). GetRendered (), "text / html;charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks Sai Kamisetti !!

Comment: @Hugo You're welcome! Please upvote the answer if it was helpful :)